# enviar datos de select por ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tengo un formulario que al seleccionar un 'select' se envia automaticamente por AJAX, la llamada funciona bien. Ahora al pasar las variables del formulario me dice Notice: Undefined index:

En el archivo index.php tengo

```js
function enviar(theForm) {
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "a.php",
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
     $('#a').html(data);
   }
 });
 event.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form role="form" name="nD" id="nD" method="post">
  <select name="d" onchange="enviar(this.form)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="a"></div>
```

En el archivo a.php tengo

```html
<h1>prueba</h1>
<?php echo $_POST['d'] ?>
```

Al quitar 'onchange="enviar(this.form)"' y colocar un 'submit' funciona bien, pero es necesario que el formulario se envie cuando se seleccione una opción del 'select'. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que reemplazar:

```
$(this).serialize()
```

Por:

```
$(theForm).serialize()
```

Así te aseguras de referenciar el formulario y no otra cosa al momento de serializar los datos.

```js
function enviar(theForm) {
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "a.php",
   data: $(theForm).serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
     $('#a').html(data);
   }
 });
 event.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form role="form" name="nD" id="nD" method="post">
  <select name="d" onchange="enviar(this.form)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra solución es declararle un evento **change** con jquery al select:option y cambiar como pasas el **serealize** de `$(this).serialize()` a `$("#nD").serialize()` :

```js
$("select[name='d']").on("change", () => {
  enviar();
});

function enviar() {

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "a.php",
   data: $("#nD").serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
     $('#a').html(data);
   }
 });
 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" name="nD" id="nD" method="post">
  <select name="d">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
  </select>
</form>
```